# How can I align an HTML table over pre-formatted text?

Tags: html, css, layout, html-table, pre

I'm trying to create an HTML page of a guitar neck using a `pre` block with a `table` aligned over it.  I need the table to line up perfectly so I can write the notes in over each fret, but for some reason my `table` will not line up over the `pre` element no matter what I do.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px">
<pre style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 0; font-size: 12px; color: #C8C8C8;">
────────┼┼─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫
        ││         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║
────────┼┼─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫────●────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫────●────╫
        ││         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║
────────┼┼─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫
        ││         ║         ║    ●    ║         ║    ●    ║         ║    ●    ║         ║    ●    ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║    ●    ║         ║    ●    ║         ║    ●    ║         ║    ●    ║         ║         ║         ║
────────┼┼─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫
        ││         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║
────────┼┼─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫────●────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫────●────╫
        ││         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║         ║
────────┼┼─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫─────────╫
</pre>

<table style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 1; font-size: 12px; color: black;">
<tr>
    <td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The end result I'm looking for is to have each "X" perfectly aligned on top of each fret to create a nice looking fretboard diagram.

This is what it looks like so far:
[image]

I've been struggling to get this to line up right for hours... I just can't seem to get it right.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a table only, save yourself the pain of trying to align to unrelated elements in CSS.

Just a quick example:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="zero">&nbsp;</td><td>e</td><td>f</td><td>f#</td><td>g</td><td>g#</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="zero">&nbsp;</td><td>b</td><td>c</td><td>c#</td><td>d</td><td>d#</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="zero">&nbsp;</td><td>g</td><td>g#</td><td>a</td><td>a#</td><td>b</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  width: 4em;
  overflow: visible;
  padding: 0.2em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 3px double black;
}

td.zero {
  width: 1em;
  border: 0;
  border-right: 4px double black;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fatjq3w2/2/